# Транзишн при наведении на посещенную ссылку - неудачный перелив

Tags: css, css3, css-animation

Итак, у нас есть два типа ссылок: непосещенные и посещенные. Сделаем первые синими, вторые красными. При наведении будем делать их темнее: непосещенные темно-синими, посещенные темно красными. Добавим транзишн для плавного перелива.

[код на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrYQx/)

```
a {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    color: #70a1e1;  
}
    a:hover {
        color: blue;
    }

a:visited {
    color: #c9342f;
}    
    a:visited:hover {
        color: maroon;
    }
```

Проблема: в firefox (как минимум): перелив на непосещенной ссылке работает нормально. На посещенной как-то странно: через синий.

**UPD:** пробовал разный порядок свойств, явное указание :link, но нужного результата не добился. В firefox, safari a:visited:hover проходит через a:hover.

Comment: Судя по всему, при наведении на посещенную ссылку срабатывает сначала a:hover с транзишном, а потом a:visited:hover.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```
a:not(:visited):hover {color: blue;}
a:visited:hover {color: maroon;}
```